# How to make indy client connect to multiple server at same time?

Tags: c++builder, indy10

I know it may be sounds weird, but is it possible for Indy client (in c++ builder xe8) to somehow(may be using any trick) connect to many server at same port (destination port) at same time?

Answer (score 0):

No. You will have to instantiate one Indy TCP client object for each connection.

Comment: Yeah, I was also thinking abt that. But I thought, may be there is a more efficient way to do that, which I dont know abt. There is another issue, I am thinking abt, that is I am checking for incoming data, in a separate thread. So do I have to use one extra thread for each client connection. Or it is possible to use same thread for each connection?

Comment: It´s possible to use the same thread for each connection. You have to create one TCP Client instance for each connection. When there is new incoming data, you have to relate the incoming data to the instance you created.

Comment: Ok. @Juliano I will try as you said and I'll inform you. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: at first I apologize for late reply. I found how to create instances in delphi, but not in c++. So I created a singly linked list, but I guess I did it wrong way. I cant give the code here, it won't be readable. So I am posting it in anew question.